# How i can get al the address location from latitude and longitude

Tags: android, android-location

i already have the latitude and longitude, i am getting almost all the location but the postalcode is always null, and the address give the street name and number i want this separate.
Well this is my code... thanks for your help..

```
Geocoder geocoder;
          List<Address> addresses;
          geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
          try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
            Address ad = addresses.get(0);
               address = ad.getAddressLine(0);
               country = ad.getCountryName();
               postalcode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
               city = ad.getLocality();
               state = ad.getAdminArea();
```

Comment: I fixed with this-----   postalcode =ad.getAddressLine(2);        int spacePos = postalcode.indexOf(" ");
     String zip = postalcode.substring(0,spacePos);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Geocoder Address returns null for fields if it doesn't have value for particular field.
Like you are getting null of postal code.
Always do null check before using field value from Geocoder Address list.

Comment: i know that but why if i do                                         addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
    address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
      city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
      country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);                                  on the country string it give me the zip code... and if i use getPostalCode(); returns null

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is called reverse geo-coding and you'll need to use a 3rd party service to be able to do this. Have a look at these links [here](http://www.geonames.org/export/reverse-geocoding.html).

Some of these services produce better results than others, but you can't rely on them. If you get a result back (or a partial one as you have) then great. But expect that you might not get anything back at all.

Comment: yup that's what i am trying to do and that way i am doing it, it gives almost all the info just zip code is null

Comment: Well it's unclear where the Geocoder class is coming from in your snippet. Whatever the 3rd party is, it might not be able to find a zip code at that location. You just won't be able to to rely on reverse geocoding. Expect to get no results back very often as your provider might not have the data in their database.